# Selecting part of a li item to get text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `li` element which looks like this:

```
<li><input type="radio" name="test" value="2" />Some text here</li>
```

How would I retrieve the text "Some text here" using JQuery? I was trying to use the children methods but I'm assuming that `li` element only has one child as the whole thing is contained within the same `li`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use just `text()` method like following.

```js
var text = $('li').text();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><input type="radio" name="test" value="2" />Some text here</li>
```

Comment: What if you have more than one **li**?

Comment: OP said he has **an `li`**. If more than one `li` he will use correct selector. The question is about getting text not selecting element. @driconmax

Comment: Thank you! I do have multiple `li`. They all have `id` attributes, so I just did `$(#li_id).text()` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You assign an id for `li` and you access via jQuery by `id`.

HTML:

```
<li id="list"><input type="radio" name="test" value="2" />Some text here</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$('# list').Html()
```

Comment: Using `.html()` returns everything inside the `li` (even the `<input type.../>`.

Comment: 1) The space in the selector will cause an error 2) it's `html()`, not `Html()` 3) this would return `<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" />Some text here`, not the content OP wants.